# What is the fine line between "confidence" and "presumption"?

Tags: style, technique, editing, academic-writing, essay

I am about to apply to a grad school, and I have prepare the SOP for it (think it like a cover letter to apply to a job). I know the rule: show what I've got, not tell how I think I'm cool. I've tried, as best as I can, to stick to this rule. I must emphasize that again: as best as I can. However, the feedback on it is [**very negative**](https://www.reddit.com/r/gradadmissions/comments/3q9e3u/here_is_my_sop_to_apply_to_berkeley_and_i_would/cwdb01c).

The commenter has already disclaimed: that just a single opinion. However, based on the number of votes, I think that maybe my SOP is really presumptuous. I just want to convey an image of confidence. I always think my readers as an audience, waiting to be entertained. I want to impress them with my writing style, but it seems that not everyone will read it as I read it.

Maybe this is the cultural issue. When I write stuff in my own language (I'm an Asian), people tell me that I have a unique style (in positive manner) (of course I have never met someone who criticize my writing style).

Here is the example. What I write is:

> Two linguists have read this work and left positive feedback. I plan to complete this work and publish it in a linguistics journal before going to grad school.

One suggestion is:

> After incorporating feedback from two linguists, I hope to have this paper published.

Another one is:

> Based on some positive feedback from two linguists who have been kind enough to review my work, I will continue my research and plan to pursue publication.

When extracting the line, I can feel "something", but I don't know what exactly it is. When reading my article as the whole, I cannot pick up other bad sentences.

So what is the fine line of "confidence" and "presumption"?

Comment: I agree with the close votes, this is asking what to write, which is currently off-topic here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is less style itself than the fact that your readers are taking your writing style as indicative of a problematic attitude.  Let's take the sentences you highlighted and the suggested improvements as a guide:

> Two linguists have read this work and left positive feedback.

Based on the suggested improvements, I'm guessing this reads as boastful and entitled.  It may seem like a completely neutral statement, but it highlights only the acclaim you've gotten.

> After incorporating feedback from two linguists...

This suggested improvement instead makes it sound like you are willing and eager to learn from others.

> Based on some positive feedback from two linguists who have been kind enough to review my work...

This suggested improvement paints you as a person who is grateful for the consideration others show to you, and respectful of those with advanced professional accomplishments.

---

> I plan to complete this work and publish it in a linguistics journal before going to grad school.

It's very difficult to get published in a reputable academic journal, and rare for anyone pre-grad-school to get such an honor.  Many may plan such an accomplishment, but few will achieve it.  Your confidence here sounds callow and naive.

> I hope to have this paper published.

This revision highlights your understanding of the difficulty of the task.

> I will continue my research and plan to pursue publication.

This does the same thing, but I think it is better, because it highlights the hard work you will do to accomplish your goal.

---

In summary, your readers on reddit want you to not merely showcase your achievements, but also to paint a picture of yourself as humble, hard-working, grateful and realistic --as well as confident.